# How to get error message in the sentance?

Tags: php, regex, message

I am using PHP code and want to fetch the error messages in the below sentences:

```
$str='Data Error (400): {"error_messages":["Currency is not included in the list (IDR, SGD)"]} | Request url: https://app.sandbox.xxx.com/snap/v1/transactions'

$str='Data Error (411): {"error_messages":["Access denied, please check client key or server key"]} | Request url: https://app.sandbox.xxx.com/snap/v1/transactions';

$str='Data Error (400): {"error_messages":["Order ID Already Paid and Utilized"]} | Request url: https://app.sandbox.xxx.com/snap/v1/transactions';

$str='Data Error (401): {"error_messages":["Invalid Transaction Type"]} | Request url: https://app.sandbox.xxx.com/snap/v1/transactions';
```

Above examples, I want to show the messages output below:

```
Currency is not included in the list (IDR, SGD)

Access denied, please check client key or server key

Order ID Already Paid and Utilized

Invalid Transaction Type
```

I am trying with below regex code:

```
preg_match('/{(.*?)}/', $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
```

But I am getting response like: `{"error_messages":["Currency is not included in the list (IDR, SGD)"]}` instead of `Currency is not included in the list (IDR, SGD)`

Please help me with how to get only the error message text?

Comment: If the strings all look like that, `if (preg_match('~\["(.*?)"]~', $str, $match)) { echo $match[1]; }` will work.

Comment: `json`, do you know what is it?

Comment: Yes @u_mulder , I have used json_encode for now. But I want to skip this line.

Comment: Those error strings don't looks very *parse-friendly* (for want of a better term) - they're not valid JSONs (though they contain a valid JSON) and they seem to use both colon and pipe as delimiters for the different data sections... personally, I'd rewrite them so they're complete JSONs and can be easily parsed to extract the code, message or URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex expression

```
preg_match('/\[\"(.*?)\"\]/', $str, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
```